# tag video not working with onmouseover and onvideoout

Tags: javascript, mysql, html, css

**i tried this onmouse over and out effect with image, there it works but not working with video tag**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <title>video</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <video src="movie.mp4" onmouseover="src='home-vid.mp4'" onmouseout="src='auto-awesome.mp4'"></video>

 </body>
```

**dont know why this tag is not working with on mouse out and on mouse over function**

**please make me this stuff clear**

Comment: maybe you miss to understand how JS work or to use

Comment: then give me some me some hint .. where i am lacking and what i need to do @donald123

Comment: Check similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159888/how-can-i-play-pause-more-than-one-video-by-mouseover

Comment: @belford thanks even i am facing the same problem .. this helps me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should execute an javascript function which change the SRC from the video tag.

This example works. Use your firebug to see it.

Like:

```js
function changeVideoSrc(src) {
document.getElementById("exampleId").src=src;
}
```

```html
<video src="movie.mp4" onmouseover="changeVideoSrc('home-vid.mp4')" onmouseout="changeVideoSrc('auto-awesome.mp4')" id="exampleId"></video>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to refer to the video tag in your events:

```
<video src="movie.mp4" onmouseover="this.src='home-vid.mp4'" onmouseout="this.src='auto-awesome.mp4'"></video>
                                    ^^^^^                                ^^^^^
```

`this.src` is the `src`attribute of your tag.

Only setting `src` without the `this`keyword sets the value of a global `src`variable. (Except for browsers like Chrome, which add an implicit `this.` infront of the `src` and other element attributes).

Comment: Not under Chrome Version 43.0.2357.134 m (64-bit). Actually, since the `this` keyword holds the element in question - you dont need it, there's an implicit `this.` in-front of the `src="blahBlah.mp4"`

Comment: @enhzflep Thanks, I didn't know that. Guess I should edit that to my answer. But since not every browser handles it the same way as Chrome, I would always write to `this.`infront of the elements properties to ensure crossbrowser compatibility.

Comment: That's a good point. Excess verbosity is far better than unexpected failure.