# Autoplay on MouseOver

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover, onmouseout

OBJECTIVE: Trying to autoplay when mouse is over the video itself.

HTML:

```
<video id = "litVideo" src="lt.mp4" onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="out(this)" controls>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function over(element) {
    alert("mouseover");
    element.append(autoplay)
   **also tried element.add(autoplay)**
}
    
function out(element) {
    alert("mouseout");
    element.remove(autoplay);  
}
```

Problem: Mouseover is alerting. However, *autoplay is not working*. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I play/pause more than one video by mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159888/how-can-i-play-pause-more-than-one-video-by-mouseover)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use play() and pause() function

```js
    const video = document.getElementById("video")
    video.onmouseover = function(){
        video.play()
    }
    video.onmouseout = function(){
        video.pause()
    }
```

```html
<video src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4" controls id="video"></video>
```

However if you want to use your approach then use

element.setAttribute("autoplay")